# Android ActionEdit crashes during saving result

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-gallery

I am developing application for TomTom navigation (Android 4.3). In my app I take some pictures and save them to some folder (external storage). When I want to edit the picture, I call the following piece of code:

```
        Intent editIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionEdit);

        string currUri = ((ImageAdapter)gallery.Adapter).currURI;
        editIntent.SetDataAndType(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(currUri), "image/*");
        editIntent.SetFlags (ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
        StartActivityForResult(editIntent, 1);
```

This opens the default android gallery where I can process my picture. After that I click on Save button and the gallery app shows dialog :"Saving picture to edited online photos" and then the gallery crashes.

When I tried it on another device (API 19), it worked great and saved the picture to the same folder as original picure. Why does the gallery try to save edited picture to the folder called "EditedOnlinePhotos" on API 18? Is there any differnce in API 19?

This is the device log at the moment the app crashes:
[device log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNgPU.png)

I spent a lot of time on it, however I was not able to solve it.

If you have any idea or need more information, feel free to reply. Thank you, I appreciate your help.

Comment: Do you have the android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"?
In what API did it crashed?

Comment: Yes, I have. It worked good on API 19 with the same permissions and crashes on API 18

Comment: If you don't have the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, please add it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I am using the following permissions:\n `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

Comment: When the application crash can you see the log? Can you paste it here?

Comment: Please check the log here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/oNgPU.png

Comment: With the log i can't help. Sorry. If you share the code in github maybe we  could help.